# Very simple bash script not working

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm making a series of bash scripts to remove to nuisance from manually typing out navigation commands into my cygwin terminal. He's one that navigates to my xampp /www/ directory:

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/www
```

When I run it with the following command:

```
$ ./www.bat
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user>cd /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/www
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What's strange is that when I type that command out manually it navigates to the intended directory without issue. My first thought is that it's an issue with Cygwin's disk drive naming, but if that was an issue it would fail upon manual typing.

What gives?

Comment: Not a cygwin user, but I would assume the problem is that you named it `.bat`, so cygwin is invoking `cmd` to run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is from the windows command line interpreter. It gets called because your script has the `.bat` extension. It should be called `www.sh` instead.

However, you can't do what you want with a script: a new process would be spawned to run your script, the new process would cd to your directory but at the end of the script the process would end and you'd be returned to the calling shell's process which would have the old current directory. You would need to source the script from bash (`. /path/to/www.sh`) so that it would run in the same process as the calling shell, but that would be overkill for what you want. Just add this to your `.bashrc` in your home directory (`/home/<user>/.bashrc`):

```
alias www='cd /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/www'
```

Comment: When I added the alias to my ~/.bashrc file and then ran the Cygwin shell I only got a "-bash: www: command not found" error. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2450099 That's strange. If you do `. ~/.bashrc` does it work?

Comment: @user2450099 Also make sure the correct file was properly modified: `grep www ~/.bashrc` should display the above line.